# Which is the most extreme thermophilic bacteria known?

Tags: bacteriology, thermophilia

Extreme thermophilic bacteria thrive at any temperature above 40/50°C. *Thermotoga Maritima* seems to be the bacteria that can survive at the highest temperature up to 90°C (reference 1, table 2). I wonder if there is a more exhaustive list of extreme thermophilic bacteria and if there is a known bacteria that can survive at higher temperatures than *Thermotoga Maritima*.

**References:**
Ref.1 Front. Microbiol., 05 November 2015 | https://doi.org/10.3389/fmicb.2015.01209
Extremely thermophilic microorganisms as metabolic engineering platforms for production of fuels and industrial chemicals

Comment: There is also the bacterium [*Aquifex pyrophilus*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0723202011802067) which is reported to grow  up to 95°C. I don’t know if this is the most extreme temperature reported for bacteria.

Answer (score 5):

[*Geogemma barossii*](https://microbewiki.kenyon.edu/index.php/Geogemma_barossii), initially designated Strain 121, can survive and reproduce at 121°C, [with an optimal growth temperature of 103°C](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/301/5635/934). It's not a bacterium though, but a member of the [Archaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea) domain.

Comment: Here is a link to an online lesson covering thermophilic and hyperthermophilic bacterial and archaea. https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-microbiology/chapter/thermophiles/

Comment: [*Methanopyrus kandleri* strain 116](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2490668/), another archaeon, is reported to grow up to 122°C with an optimum growth temperature of 105°C. In the paper they also explain that it is difficult to compare this species with others from different studies due to the dependence of growth temperatures on culture conditions.

Comment: Is this the same as what grows at Yellowstone's geysers? Because they say "The water can be as hot as 204 degrees and the steam can exceed 300 degrees." That's on the Fahrenheit scale. Converting to Celsius, it's 95.5 and 148.9. https://whyy.org/segments/the-biodiversity-of-heat-loving-bacteria-in-yellowstone-rivals-a-rainforest/